# how to make an operation in parallel using spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following `data.frame` in `spark`

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit

ddf = spark.createDataFrame([[None, 'Michael',2],
                             [30, 'Andy',3],
                             [19, 'Justin',4],
                             [30, 'James Dr No From Russia with Love Bond',6]],
                            schema=['age', 'name','weights'])
ddf.show()
```

In this trivial example I would like to create two columns: One with the `weighted.mean` of the `age` if `age>29` (with name `weighted_age`) and the other the `age^2` if `age<=29` (with the name `age_squared`)

```
In order to do so I can do this

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
weightedMean = ddf.filter(f.col('age')>29).select(f.sum(f.col('age')*f.col('weights'))/f.sum(f.col('weights'))).first()[0]

ddf.withColumn('weighted_age', f.when(f.col('age') > 29, weightedMean))\
    .withColumn('age_squared', f.when(f.col('age') <= 29, f.col('age')*f.col('age')))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

My question is, is there any way to do this operation in parallel for the two `if` conditions ( so, two columns are created. One is created under the condition age >29 (first `if` condition), and the other is created under the condition age <= 29 (second `if` condition) )

Comment: @eliasah I am sorry, but I do not see the parallelization thing in the question you linked

Comment: I am not sure if i get your question completely, the 2 calculations are performed in a lazy manner and performed in a single stage and in a single task, so spark runs the 2 operations at the same time.